# Chartjs: Why do I have 2 Y Axis labels?

Tags: chart.js

My chart data is working, but I would like the Y axis to start below my lowest value and extend just a bit above the largest value and I was looking at the yAxes-> ticks-> min/max to do this.  But when I add this to the options, a second second Y axis label is added with a scale of -1.0 to 1.0; I'm not sure how to get rid of that.  I have attached some screen shots and some mocked up js code.  Thanks

```js
    var chartData = {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
                datasets: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Dataset 1',
                    borderColor: 'blue',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    fill: false,
                    data: [
                        85, 80, 75
                    ]
                }, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    label: 'Dataset 2',
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    data: [
                        90, 85, 80
                    ],
                    borderColor: 'white',
                    borderWidth: 2
                }, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    label: 'Dataset 3',
                    backgroundColor: 'green',
                    data: [
                        95, 90, 85
                    ]
                }]
            };

            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myMixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartData,
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'A Funky Label'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: false
                        }],
                        yAxes: [
                            {
                                ticks: {
                                    max: 100,
                                    min: 50,
                                    stepSize: 10,
                                    callback: function (value, index, values) {
                                        return value + " HP";
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                stacked: false
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                            left: 10,
                            right: 10,
                            top: 0,
                            bottom: 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```

[image: Image with no ticks - starts at 0]

[image: Img with ticks and second y axis]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer:
I was trying to determine if I wanted a stacked bar chart or regular bar chart with multiple series chart.  Anyway, after deciding to stick with the regular bar chart with multiple series I removed this from my options section:

```
stacked: false
```

Once removed the second Y axis disappeared